# How to check for a value after curl or wget?

Tags: linux, wget, curl

I need to curl/wget a page and make sure it returned a particular value (else return 1), something like this:

```
curl http://example.com/something/run | grep -e '^success!$' || return 1
```

Which flags should I use in curl or wget? It's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to suppress the error output from `curl` with `2> /dev/null`. Then, pipe the output to `grep -qc`, which will suppress normal output and just display the count of matches.

You can then proceed as usual.

```
curl "http://example.com" 2> /dev/null | grep -qci -e 'something' && echo "yay"
```